# #1005 - Can't create table 'disertation.#sql-d38_40' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, sql

Cannot create foreign key, here is my two table
[image]

I want to link **stud_id**  with **sid**, i,ve tried this query:

```
    ALTER TABLE student
ADD FOREIGN KEY (sid)
REFERENCES marks(stud_id)
```

I go this error

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'disertation.#sql-d38_40' (errno: 150)
```

Comment: NULL yes on sid NULL no on stud_id.Both defaults have to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Since the error message refers to a completely different table, "dissertation", I'd guess that you have multiple statements in your SQL editor, and that you are either executing all of them, or aren't executing the one that you think you are.

Many SQL editors will execute everything unless you highlight something, then they will just execute what is highlighted.

Comment: "dissertation" is my database name

Comment: I still think that my answer is probably correct - the error message says "can't create table dissertation", so you're clearly trying to execute a "create table" statement, not an "alter table" statement.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, to solve the problem, we need to make both column data unique thus only we can link the two column